# SQL Exec CrossTab Issue - Incorrect Syntax Near ','

Tags: sql, syntax, crosstab

```
set nocount on

declare @max_period30 datetime
declare @max_year int
declare @max_month int

create table #Temp
(inv_month          int
,inv_year           int
,action_group  varchar(50)
,submitted_by_action int
)

insert #Temp
select a.start_month,a.start_year,a.action_group,isnull(count(*),0)
from 
 (select  
       start_month = datepart(month,tb.start_time)
      ,start_year = datepart(year,tb.start_time)
      ,tc.action_group
   from BLAH..the_best tb
   left join BLAH..the_categories tc  
   on tb.action_type  = tc.action_type
   group by tb.id,tb.start_time,tc.action_group
   ) a
group by a.start_year,a.start_month,a.action_group 
order by a.start_year,a.start_month

SET @max_period30 = (SELECT MAX(CONVERT(DATETIME,(CONVERT(CHAR(2),DATEPART(mm,start_time)) + '-01-' + CONVERT(CHAR(4),DATEPART(yy,start_time))),101))
                  FROM BLAH..the_best)

SET @max_year  = DATEPART(YEAR,@max_period30)
SET @max_month = DATEPART(MONTH,@max_period30)

DELETE FROM #Temp
 WHERE inv_year  = @max_year
 AND   inv_month = @max_month

INSERT #Temp
SELECT inv_month,inv_year,'Total',SUM(submitted_by_action)
FROM #Temp
GROUP BY inv_month,inv_year,action_group

UPDATE #Temp
SET action_group = 'No Action Type'
WHERE action_group IS NULL
 
INSERT #Temp
SELECT  DATEPART(MONTH,DATEADD(MONTH,-1,@max_period30)),DATEPART(YEAR,DATEADD(MONTH,-1,@max_period30)),a.action_group,0 
FROM 
(SELECT DISTINCT action_group FROM BLAH..the_categories
   UNION 
 SELECT 'No Action Type') a
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT DISTINCT inv_month,inv_year,action_group FROM  #Temp) b
ON  a.action_group = b.action_group
WHERE  b.action_group IS NULL

EXEC CrossTab
'select  ''Tname''= ''T031'', inv_year,inv_month,action_group,submitted_by_action from #Temp',
'action_group',
'sum(submitted_by_action)[]',
'Tname,inv_year,inv_month',
'',
'inv_year,inv_month'
```

ERROR:

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near ','.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near 'A'.
```

SQL newbie here that has inherited running this stored proc. It has been unchanged for probably a decade and ran with no issues, until this month's run.

The most I can narrow it down is to the CrossTab part at the end. But I have no idea what 'A' or ',' the error is referencing.

Does anyone see where this error is pointing to? Any help/input is appreciated.

Thanks!

Unfortunately, I can't really explain what the data originally looks like but the intended output is like this

[image: 1]

Comment: In all likelihood if this has been running for years with no issues and is now complaining about a syntax issue, someone must have changed it. Procedures don't syntactically break on their own.

Comment: @Charleh thanks for the reply. Unfortunately I am certain the proc is untouched. There is about 30 procs that I run for a monthly report, about 8 of them are throwing this error this month. I am the only one that has any relation to these old procs and I haven't touched them. They're all throwing the same error.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Crosstab, but something doesn't look right to me in the "EXEC Crosstab" section at the end. I guess the line-broken strings are concatenated without any + symbols? But then if they are being concatenated, won't the very end look like this? "Tname,inv_year,inv_monthinv_year,inv_month"